# Array Iteration using foreach

Tags: php

I have something like a json array output, it comes like :

```
{
  "data": [
    {
      "color"
      "size"
      "id"
      "weight"
    },
    {
      "color"
      "size"
      "id"
      "weight"
    },
```

And so on.
The array name is called $cars.
I need to loop through all the array and get all car sizes.

something like:

```
foreach ($cars as $value) {
    $carsize=[data][i][size]
```

Thanks.

Comment: Your json array is syntactically wrong.  No way it would parse.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure you parse into an array when using `json_decode()`, then iterate over the data like so:

```
$array = json_decode($json, true);
foreach ($array['data'] as $data) {
    $carsize = $data['size'];
    echo $carsize;
}
```

Comment: Yes, i gues this would do the right work, one more question if i need to extract the first car size i'd echo it how? i mean echo [data][0][size] ?

Comment: You don't need to use a foreach to access a specific item. Given the decoded array, `echo $array['data'][0]['size'];` would do.

Answer (score 1):

`$cars =` [`json_decode`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php)`($cars)` should do what you  need.

Comment: Hey thanks, sorry, maybe i explained myself wrong, i need to do this in php.. i mean, as the array was in php

Comment: @Eri you're saying that the array has already been decoded?